# How do you cause a Server Kendo Grid Detail Template to display in the open position?

Tags: kendo-grid

I want to display a Kendo Grid with a Detail Template with all of the detail rows in the open position.

I am using Server binding, so many of the events for the detail template that might be useful will not fire.

I have tried using HtmlTableAttributes, but this also does not seem to work.

From the IE F12 analysis, the grid comes up with the detail template tables set with a display state of none, and then the display state is removed when the open icon is pushed.

I have a client who wants all of the detail templates in the open position.

This is my Kendo code:

```
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
                .Name("PriorityListingGrid1")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(e => e.name).Title("Immunotherapy Open Studies").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;" })
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:larger;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;" })
                    .Width("100%");
            })
            .Events(e => { e.DetailInit("detailInit"); })
                            .DetailTemplate(e => myDetailDetailViewTemplate1(this,e.siteSlotData, e.id))
                                                                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "min-height:600px;" })
                                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                                .Server()
                                                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.id))
                                                .PageSize(Model.Count())
                                                     )
        )
        @helper myDetailDetailViewTemplate1(WebViewPage page, IEnumerable<AdminApplicationsLibrary.Immunology.SiteSlotData> f, int id, int ignored = 0)
            {
                String grid_ref = String.Format("details_{0}", id);
                this.Page.tgrid_ref = grid_ref;
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid(f)
                    .Name(grid_ref)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:104.3%;Left:-41px;" })
                    .TableHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:8pt;" })
                    .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(o => o.RxStudy.irb).Template(@<text>
                                                                        @Html.ActionLink(@item.RxStudy.irb.ToString(), "Details", "ImmunoRxStudy", new { id = @item.RxStudy.id }, null)
                                                                        </text>).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Width("10%");
                            columns.Bound(o => o.priority).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Width("5%");
                            columns.Bound(o => o.RxStudy.short_name).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Width("19%");
                            columns.Bound(o => o.Status).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Title("Status").Width("5%");
                            columns.Bound(o => o.slots).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Width("8%");
                            columns.Bound(o => o.notes).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Width("20%");
                            columns.Bound(o => o.pre_tx).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Width("5%");
                            columns.Bound(o => o.archival).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Width("5%");
                            columns.Bound(o => o.on_tx).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Width("5%");
                            columns.Bound(o => o.RxStudy.phase).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Width("10%");
                            columns.Bound(o => o.RxStudy.open_date).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Width("8%");
                            columns.Bound(o => o.RxStudy.rn_cra).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Width("10%");
                        })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Server().Model(model => model.Id(p => p.id)))
                )
            }
```

How do I make the detail template display in the selected position for all of the detail templates when using server-side binding?

I really do not want to go with Ajax binding at this point unless I have no other option.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I discovered the answer I was looking for.

The main grid needs to be changed to:

```
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
                .Name("PriorityListingGrid1")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(e => e.name).Title("Immunotherapy Open Studies").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;" })
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:larger;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;" })
                    .Width("100%");
            })
            .DetailTemplate(e => myDetailDetailViewTemplate1(this,e.siteSlotData, e.id))
                                                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "min-height:600px;" })
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Server()
                                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.id))
                                .PageSize(Model.Count())
                                        )
            .RowAction(r => { r.DetailRow.Expanded = true; })
        )
```

The RowAction method allows for this particular result.  I would note that I could not find this anywhere in the Telerik documentation or examples.  I found a reference to using this on google and stackoverflow.

:-)